# Is having two stages one on top of the other a bad idea? libgdx

Tags: java, performance, libgdx

Logically, my game can be separated into two parts that coexist:

1. The actual game where entities (`Actors`) enter, exit and interact.
2. A "meta part" of the game, where images and/or text appear and disappear. This is sort of a HUD but not exactly since its entities (`Actors` as well) can appear anywhere on the screen and is dynamic.

The `Actors` in part 1 do not interact with the `Actors` in part 2 and visa-versa.

Currently, I've implemented the two parts as `Stages` and it works well. The main loop basically looks like this:

```
public void render(float delta) {
    // ...         
    mainStage.act();
    mainStage.draw();

    metaStage.act();
    metaStage.draw();
}
```

**The separation into two `Stages` is done only for the sake of clean and logical code.** My question is am I paying a high price in performance? I.e., is it much more expensive, performance wise, to draw a certain amount of actors in two `stages` rather than with one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be barely any performance impact. Possibly one extra draw call because the first stage gets flushed before the second one starts drawing. You probably already have a lot of draw calls for your UI if you use Buttons (which you could reduce by calling `.setTransform(false)` on them). If a Button or Table is left with the default of transform being on, then they always each cause a batch flush.

There is a potential waste of memory if you let each stage have its own SpriteBatch. But this is easily avoided by instantiating a SpriteBatch and passing it to the constructors of both stages.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on sharing the same SpriteBatch!